# Accessing type arguments from generic types used in typebounds

Tags: java, generics

I have discovered the following problems with generics. Consider the generic interface

```
public interface A<X> {
    X get();
    void doStuff(X x);
}
```

Now, let's assume the following method definition:

```
public <T extends A<?>> void foo(T t) {
    bar(t);
}
```

Due to the wildcard, the type information for the return type of get() is insufficient. Therefore, I have to delegate to another method that "binds" this wildcard to a fresh type variable:

```
private <X> void bar(A<X> t) {
    X x = t.get();
    t.doStuff(x);
}
```

The invocation of bar() in foo is not allowed, the compiler outputs the following error message:

> The method bar(A) in the type test is not applicable for the arguments (T)

However, if I change the method foo() to

```
public <T extends A<?>> void foo(T t) {
    A<?> u = t; // No explicit cast required, no "unchecked" warning!
    bar(u);
}
```

it works. Why? Is this a compiler error? Any comments on this would be very much appreciated.

Notes:

- The reason why I don't simply declare method foo as void foo(A) is that I'm actually using the upper type bound interesection (&).
- The reason why I don't declare X as a type variable in foo() is that I actually have the problem at class level and don't want to unnecessarily increase the number of type parameters of this class.

Comment: are you using the -Xlint compiler flag? If not, try compiling with that

Comment: I agree with @kan. The java compiler does, in fact compile this. I used 1.6.0_27. Eclipse does give the exact error you gave, so maybe you're using it?

Comment: Created the eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364200 using @kan's example.

Comment: Does not compile using javac 1.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the code:

```
public class Test
{
    public interface A<X> {
        X get();
        void doStuff(X x);
    }
    public <T extends A<?>> void foo(T t) {
        bar(t);
    }

    private <X> void bar(A<X> t) {
        X x = t.get();
        t.doStuff(x);
    }
}
```

it works. javac 1.6.0_22. Where do you have the error? Or I using another code?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it on monday on my machine at work, I don't know exactly which javac version I'm using there. I just tested it at home and it doesn't compile using javac 1.6.0_11...

Comment: Btw, the error simply is "<X>bar(Test.A<X>) in Test cannot be applied to (T)", with the marker pointing at the bar() call.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
public class Test
{
    public interface A<X> {
        X get();
        void doStuff(X x);
    }
    public <T extends A<?>> void foo(T t) {
        bar(t);
    }

    private <X> void bar(A<X> t) {
        X x = t.get();
        t.doStuff(x);
    }
}
```

compiles for only select versions of Java 1.6. This [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364200) was logged for eclipse, but was rejected with the following explanation by Srikanth Sankaran:

> I believe the eclipse compiler behavior is correct  and is matched by
>   JDK5 and JDK7 (latest). It would appear the JDK6 behavior is a
>   regression which has since been fixed.
>
> Basically, here is a brief explanation of what is going on here:
>
> Given the generic method bar and the call site as given by bar(t), the
>   inference algorithm has no constrains to work with to infer the type
>   of the type variable X. So after considering the arguments and
>   expected return type etc, X is still unresolved and per specification
>   is resolved to be the published lower bound - i.e X is inferred to be
>   Object and the method becomes void bar(A) t); Since the actual
>   parameters cannot be converted to formal parameters, the inferred
>   method has to be rejected leaving us with no applicable candidates.
>   Hence the call must be rejected.
>
> The reason the call bar( ( A )t ); succeeds is that in this case X
>   is inferred to be "capture#1-of ?" and the generic method
>   parameterized with this substitution becomes void bar(A) for which the parameter compatibility holds.